# How to move a node from one simulation to another

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-directed-graph

I'm trying to move nodes from one `forceSimulation` to another, and I'm expecting the nodes to leave one cluster and drift over to another.  However, it seems that once the simulation has settled into a stable pattern the forces stop being applied.

Here's the codepen:
[Migrating Nodes](https://jsfiddle.net/davidprea/cwruyv5b/15/)

And a snippet:

```js
const width = 600;
const height = 200;

var nodes;
var simulations;

function loaded() {
  d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  test();
}

function test() {

  nodes = [];
  nodes[0] = d3.range(50).map(function() {
    return {
      radius: 4,
      color: "blue"
    };
  })

  nodes[1] = d3.range(50).map(function() {
    return {
      radius: 4,
      color: "red"
    };
  })

  simulations = [null, null];

  update(0);
  update(1);

  setTimeout(startMigration, 1000);

}


function update(index) {

  simulations[index] = d3.forceSimulation(nodes[index])
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(10))
    .force('x', d3.forceX().x(function(d) {
      return width * (index + 1) / 3;
    }))
    .force('y', d3.forceY().y(function(d) {
      return height / 2;
    }))
    .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {
      return d.radius;
    }))
    .on('tick', ticked);

  function ticked() {
    var u = d3.select('svg')
      .selectAll('.circle' + index)
      .data(nodes[index])
      .join('circle')
      .attr('class', 'circle' + index)
      .attr('r', function(d) {
        return d.radius;
      })
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        //return colorScale(d.category);
        return d.color;
      })
      .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });
  }

}


function startMigration() {
  setInterval(function() {
    if (nodes[1].length > 10) {
      nodes[0].push(nodes[1].pop());

      d3.select('svg')
        .selectAll('.circle0')
        .data(nodes[0]);
      simulations[0].nodes(nodes[0]);

      d3.select('svg')
        .selectAll('.circle1')
        .data(nodes[1]);
      simulations[1].nodes(nodes[1]);

    }
  }, 250);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="loaded()">
  <div id='layout'>
    <div id='container'>
      <svg id="graph" />
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

`nodes` is an array of two datasets, and `simulations` is an array of two simulations.

Here is where I create the `forceSimulation`s:

```
function update(index) {
    
    simulations[index] = d3.forceSimulation(nodes[index])
        .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(10))
        .force('x', d3.forceX().x(function(d) {
            return width * (index + 1) / 3;
        }))
        .force('y', d3.forceY().y(function(d) {
            return height/2;
        }))
        .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {
            return d.radius;
        }))
        .on('tick', ticked);

    function ticked() {
        var u = d3.select('svg')
            .selectAll('.circle' + index)
            .data(nodes[index])
            .join('circle')
            .attr('class', 'circle' + index)
            .attr('r', function(d) {
                return d.radius;
            })
            .style('fill', function(d) {
                //return colorScale(d.category);
                return d.color;
            })
            .attr('cx', function(d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr('cy', function(d) {
                return d.y;
            });
    }

}
```

A this is the code that starts getting called periodically 1000ms after the simulation starts to move nodes from one simulation to the other:

```
nodes[0].push(nodes[1].pop());
            
d3.select('svg')
   .selectAll('.circle0')
   .data(nodes[0]);
simulations[0].nodes(nodes[0]);
            
d3.select('svg')
   .selectAll('.circle1')
   .data(nodes[1]);
simulations[1].nodes(nodes[1]);
```

The effect I was hoping for is that nodes would leave the red cluster and drift over to join the blue cluster.  Why do they slow down and stop? The problem gets worse the longer I wait after the initial load.  I get the feeling there's something fundamental about `forceSimulation` I'm not understanding.  I would have thought that they would get as close as they could to the (`forceX`, `forceY`) of the simulation to which they belong.

A secondary question is whether all the steps in the code snippet above are necessary.  Do I need to reassign data to both selections, and reassign nodes to both simulations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of force simulations with user interaction 'reheat' the simulation during drag operations with [`simulation.alpha(n).restart()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/main/README.md#simulation_alpha). See this [observable](https://observablehq.com/@bumbeishvili/d3-v6-force-directed-graph-with-more-natural-drag-attractio) for example.

You can do this without user interaction in `setMigration` function to keep the simulation animation updated (keep it 'warm' so to speak) until sufficient circles have moved from 'red' to 'blue'. The two lines to add are:

```
simulations[0].alpha(0.15).restart();
simulations[1].alpha(0.15).restart();
```

If you increase 0.15 (upto 1) you will see that both simulations are more 'excitable' as the migration occurs. 0.15 seemed like a pleasant visual experience for me. This seems to work without the `.restart()` so you can play around with that too likely depending on how long you wait to start `setMigration`.

For your second question - since each simulation was initialised to `nodes[0]` and `nodes[1]` then the `d3.select('svg').selectAll('.circleN')` can be commented out because you already changed the array content with `nodes[0].push(nodes[1].pop())`.

Working example below:

```js
const width = 600;
const height = 200;

var nodes;
var simulations;

function loaded() {
  d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  test();
}

function test() {

  nodes = [];
  nodes[0] = d3.range(50).map(function() {
    return {
      radius: 4,
      color: "blue"
    };
  })

  nodes[1] = d3.range(50).map(function() {
    return {
      radius: 4,
      color: "red"
    };
  })

  simulations = [null, null];

  update(0);
  update(1);

  setTimeout(startMigration, 1000);

}


function update(index) {

  simulations[index] = d3.forceSimulation(nodes[index])
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(10))
    .force('x', d3.forceX().x(function(d) {
      return width * (index + 1) / 3;
    }))
    .force('y', d3.forceY().y(function(d) {
      return height / 2;
    }))
    .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {
      return d.radius;
    }))
    .on('tick', ticked);

  function ticked() {
    var u = d3.select('svg')
      .selectAll('.circle' + index)
      .data(nodes[index])
      .join('circle')
      .attr('class', 'circle' + index)
      .attr('r', function(d) {
        return d.radius;
      })
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        //return colorScale(d.category);
        return d.color;
      })
      .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });
  }

}


function startMigration() {
  setInterval(function() {
    if (nodes[1].length > 10) {
      nodes[0].push(nodes[1].pop());

      //d3.select('svg')
      //  .selectAll('.circle0')
      //  .data(nodes[0]);
      simulations[0].nodes(nodes[0]);

      //d3.select('svg')
      //  .selectAll('.circle1')
      //  .data(nodes[1]);
      simulations[1].nodes(nodes[1]);
      
      // reheat the simulations
      simulations[0].alpha(0.15).restart();
      simulations[1].alpha(0.15).restart();

    }
  }, 250);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="loaded()">
  <div id='layout'>
    <div id='container'>
      <svg id="graph" />
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, Robin!  That 'alpha' setting...the 'heat' of the simulation...is exactly the thing I suspected was in there somewhere.